# Split blogger Post into multiple pages

Tags: javascript, css, blogger, helper

I saw a split blogger Post on GitHub https://github.com/aitibimah/split-blogger-post
and I installed all the code in my template.
But I need help on what code to add in between post for the blogger split to work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use ⏩ to split the post.

Here is how the script works

```js
$('.aiti-body').prop('innerHTML').split('⏩');
```

Comment: I added this**⏩** but the post is not splitting, you can check it [link](https://pstoriesandjokes.blogspot.com/2021/09/next-prev.html). Please i really need it

Comment: @Abdulazeez it's because you need jQuery, add jQuery script anywhere before the split script `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: the <data:post.body/> tag is affecting my pages like contact and sitemap page. If I remove the tag the pages will show but if I add it back the pages won't show.. What can I do to amend it

Comment: I think you should make a new question with more details